# Login System. StreamReader convertion to string

Tags: c#, .net

Hello i want to add a login function to my program.

I am stucking with convertion from stream reader to string type

```
HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(
site+"register.php?u="
+username+"&p="+sha1(password)
+"&e="+email+"&tmp="+sha1(act_link= new StreamReader(wr.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
```

It says:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'system.io.streamreader' to 'string'

How could I solve this in my case? I'm confused since I think it should be all in one line.

Comment: `HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(...sha1(act_link = new StreamReader(wr...);` Are you try to use wr for creating wr?!

Comment: i tried to follow this tutorial https://www.se7ensins.com/forums/threads/creating-a-register-login-activation-c-php-sql.994890/

I currently using another method, also with php. But i would love to try this example with the activation but i wasn'T able to resolve it so i am asking here. I am pretty new to programming and I want to know how to resolve such issue since i wasn't able and want to learn from errors.

Comment: George you're right i was also failing with wr creating wr >.<

Answer (score 0):

I got it ^^

```
public static string register(string username, string password, string email, string act_link)
    {
        string s = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            string site = "http://yoursite.com/";
            HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(site + "register.php?u=" + username + "&p=" + sha1(password) + "&e=" + email + "&tmp=" + sha1(act_link));
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wr.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
            s = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }
        return s;
    }
```